# Texture and Lines not blending in WebGL

Tags: webgl, textures, lines

I'm supposed to be having a 2d program using webgl and supposed to have a picture over the canvas which is a texture and above it i draw lines using webgl also. But the thing is both have different shader programs and whenever i'm drawing lines it's getting messed up. So Can anyone help?